# chef - bootstraping localhost results in refused connection

Tags: ruby, ssh, localhost, chef-infra

I'm learning Chef (`12.10.24`) and am trying to build a cookbook with recipes for provisioning machines that I'll do Ruby development on.

I'm trying to use `knife bootstrap` to set up my laptop as a node but am getting a connection error that I'm not sure how to get around. Here is the output:

```
➜  chef-repo$ knife bootstrap localhost -yN my-macbook-pro -p 2200 -x david -P [password]
Creating new client for my-macbook-pro
Creating new node for my-macbook-pro
Connecting to localhost
ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:2200
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

Connecting to `chef-server` is fine but I can't connecting to `localhost`. Any suggestions about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: There's a ssh server on your laptop listening on port 2200 on every address ? what it says is that it can't connect to port 2200 on 127.0.0.1, checking a `netstat -an` output to confirm would be great. (Assuming your running the knife command from your laptop)

Comment: found out the prob is that the ssh daemon isn't on be default in OSX (sorry for not mentioning my OS in the question)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unlikely to help anyone else in the future and it is unrelated to chef at all.

Comment: It's not unrelated to chef. It's indirectly related to chef and it seems to me quite likely that there might be other OSX users who would want to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It's just related to the ssh daemon, any attempt to ssh (from chef or whatever tool) would have failed the same way with the same kind of message. Anyway, that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I neglected to mention that I am using OSX El Capitan. It turns out that the ssh daemon isn't on by default in OSX.

Turning it on in System Preferences > Sharing (check `Remote Login`) fixed the problem.